# How to read the color of excel tab in order to use it to color a cell or a box ?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use color a box with the exact color of the tab , so whenever I Change the color of the tab the color of the can be changed accordingly, any ideas how to get the rgb code of the tab color for example ?

Comment: The tab colour can be found in the worsheet tab property; eg. `Sheet1.Tab.ColorIndex` returns the index of the Color on the [color palette](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm). You'll have to think carefully about which event you use to trigger the box to change colour though - perhaps post the code you've written so far to get more directed advice

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the helpful answers , the following line did what I wanted :

`ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Check Box " & j)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Worksheets(thename).Tab.color`

with j an index , and thename as a variable reading the Name of the tab at every Iteration ..

Cheers ,